How to implement persistent client-server communication in ROS2?
In ROS1, it was possible to declare communication between a client and a server as persistent using a flag in the client declaration, for example:
auto client = node.serviceClient<my_service::MyService>("/my_service", true);

This feature was very useful for improving performance when a server was queried multiple times.
I know that in ROS2 things have changed, but is there a way to achieve equivalent behavior? How can I implement persistent service communication in ROS2 to maintain a connection and improve performance?
Thank you in advance

Is it possible you are searching for QoS settings? It sounds like you are trying to change the "Durability" behavior.

I had already looked into QoS, but it doesn't seem to me that any of the settings replicate ROS1's persistent client-server connection. According to the page you linked, "Durability" refers to the ability to resend the last message when a new subscription is made. However, the persistent connection in ROS1 allows for keeping the communication open between client and server to avoid the repeated setup steps (1, 2, 3, and 4) each time the service is called, as detailed here.

I am unsure this stills plays a role in a highly performant Ros2 underlay. As by your provided link "default, service connections are stateless. For each call a client wishes to make, it repeats the steps of looking up the service on the Master and exchanging request/response data over a new connection.
The stateless approach is generally more robust as it allows a service node to be restarted, but this overhead can be high if frequent, repeated calls are made to the same service."

In ROS 2, Quality of Service (QoS) settings apply to both publishers and subscribers, as well as to services and actions.
In Services, QoS settings for services ensure that the communication between service clients and service servers adheres to specified QoS policies. This includes controlling aspects like reliability and durability for service requests and responses. So by reading the Qos policies documentation, you can make the service behave the way you want.      you can define custom QoS settings:
    rclcpp::QoS qos_profile(rclcpp::KeepLast(10));
    qos_profile.best_effort(); // Or qos_profile.reliable() for RELIABLE policy

    // Create a client for the service with custom QoS settings
    client_ = this->create_client<my_service::srv::MyService>("/my_service",qos_profile);


please edit your question instead of posting it as an answer

It is the answer to the question @C_T asked , not a question
I was saying that the same service behavior can be reached using QoS, just read the documentation.

sorry didn't show like that in my interface :/

It's all good I hope that my answer is helpful.
